# What causes this exception Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()"

Tags: java

I have developed a modular javafx application using eclipse, jdk14 and javafx14. However, when i try to run the application from the IDE i am getting an exception stated below. This started happening after i made attempts to modularize fontawesome-8.2 jar so that i can use it in my modular application. The modularization seem to have worked except for the exception i am getting when i try to run the application. I have googled but i don't seem to find a working solution to this problem. Your assistance and guidance will be appreciated. Below is an excerpt from the stacktrace:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because the return value of "java.lang.Class.getResource(String)" is null
at fontawesomefx/de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcon.(FontAwesomeIcon.java:31)
... 23 more